# Replacing BaseCommandController and SimpleFormController with annotated Controller in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Where can I find some examples on replacing/migrating Spring Framework controllers from version 2 to version 4? By that I mean migrate/replace SimpleFormController and BaseCommandController into an annotated controller @Controller. I am new to the Spring Framework.
For example, my old controller uses onBind(HttpServletRequest request, Object command) method. How can I migrate method like onBind and onBindAndvalidate using the new spring libraries?

Thank you

Comment: I am also trying to refactor SimpleFormController.isFormChangeRequest with the new Spring 4 libraries

Comment: I guess you have got a solution for this by this time.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently doing this upgradation task and I found a very helpful guide to do upgradation.

posting here so that it can be used further by other potential developers.

1. SimpleFormController vs @Controller
   In XML-based Spring MVC web application, you create a form controller by extending the SimpleFormController class.
   In annotation-based, you can use @Controller instead
2. formBackingObject() vs RequestMethod.GET
   In SimpleFormController, you can initialize the command object for binding in the formBackingObject() method. In annotation-based, you can do the same by annotated the method name with @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET).
3. onSubmit() vs RequestMethod.POST
   In SimpleFormController, the form submission is handle by the onSubmit() method. In annotation-based, you can do the same by annotated the method name with @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST).
4. referenceData() vs @ModelAttribute
   In SimpleFormController, usually you put the reference data in model via referenceData() method, so that the form view can access it. In annotation-based, you can do the same by annotated the method name with @ModelAttribute.
5. initBinder() vs @InitBinder
   In SimpleFormController, you define the binding or register the custom property editor via initBinder() method. In annotation-based, you can do the same by annotated the method name with @InitBinder.
6. From Validation
   In SimpleFormController, you have to register and map the validator class to the controller class via XML bean configuration file, and the validation checking and work flows will be executed automatically.
   In annotation-based, you have to explicitly execute the validator and define the validation flow in the @Controller class manually.

You can see the example implementation screenshots at [Click Here](https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/)